# Python Mysql How to updating columns from a list/variable in a efficient way?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to python and MySQL too. I'm trying to build a soccer database with MySQL. In a database created two tables, I did with them basic update things, updating one row at the time, or a few rows, but I want automating the whole process and especially updating from a variable or a list. I have a table, where I recorded the past matches (in the season so far) and I have another table, where I want to create automatically the actual soccer table based on their performance on the season table so far.

```
my_sq8 = "UPDATE bundesligatabella_2020_2021 SET F = %s, A = %s WHERE Team = '%s' VALUES (%s, %s, 
%s)"
val = [
(9, 5, "Bayern München"),
(8, 7, "Augsburg"),
(4, 3, "Bielefeld"),
]
my_cursor.executemany(my_sq8, val)
mydb.commit()
```

This is my first attempt with just 3 teams, where I want to update the number of Goals for the specific team, but I always get an error. Can someone help me how can I fix this?

In the feature I plan, that I do every arithmetical thing in a bigger list, and update from there specific tot the team. Maybe I'm wrong, let me know, if you have an idea, to update faster or better the values, instead of making variables for all stats and for all teams.

This is my error message for the code above:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File \python\database.py", line 141, in 
> my_cursor.executemany(my_sq8, val)
> File "\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 675, in executemany
> self.execute(operation, params)
> File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 558, in execute
> stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
> File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 85, in **call**
> raise errors.ProgrammingError(
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: We'd be able to help better if you include the full error and traceback with your question.

Comment: That values... part of your update sql should not be there.

Comment: "In the feature..."   Then it would be a great idea to rename `bundesligatabella_2020_2021` to `bundesligatabella`, and add a column like `Fussballspielsaison`, (or just the date when the match was played)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are mixed in your case. The `VALUES` keyword should be removed. Whereas the immediate source of the error is that you have `6` parameters within the statement while there should be `3`. Btw, the variable might be quoted within the `val` list, and you can get rid of single quotes wrapping up the last variable(`%s`) within the sql statement.

So, you can fix the syntax such as

```
my_sq8 = "UPDATE bundesligatabella_2020_2021 SET F = %s, A = %s WHERE Team = %s"
val = [
    (9, 5, 'Bayern München'),
    (8, 7, 'Augsburg'),
    (4, 3, 'Bielefeld'),
    ]
my_cursor.executemany(my_sq8, val)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'm stuck with this for hours :)